# Converting multiple row data to single row in R

Tags: r

I have same data set but with 886,120 rows (34 ID and each ID has 22,271 rows) to be convert to 34 rows with 22,271 columns.

```
Raw  ID(34)  Values(22,271 for each ID)

1   AND 0.08333
2   BEL 0.08333
3   ARR 0.2292
4   AND 0.3056
5   AND 0.3056
6   BEL 0.3333
7   AKT 0.3421
8   BEL 0.3667
9   AKTK 0.3684
10  ARR 0.4583
11  ARR 0.4583
12  AKTK 0.7105
...
886120  ARR 0.2152

===========================================
To be convert with the following format:
===========================================
ID     Value1   Value2   Value3   ... Value22,721

AKTK    0.7105  0.3421  0.3684  
AND 0.3056  0.3056  0.08333 
ARR 0.4583  0.4583  0.2292  
BEL 0.3333  0.3667  0.08333
```

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Do you need the `sum` of `mean` of the multiple rows? Try `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, N:= paste0('Value', 1:.N), ID]; dcast(df1, ID~N, value.var='Values', mean)` or change to `sum`

Comment: This is known as reshaping from long to wide. There are several methods available and this is certainly a duplicate question in that regard

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshape data from long to wide, with time in new wide variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320515/reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-with-time-in-new-wide-variable-name)

Comment: @Alex this one is a bit different because you have to 1) sort, and then 2) add in the "column ID" column to get the solution.

Comment: @atiretoo I'm sure there are very minor differences. The issue that I have is that it's still essentially duplicate work, meaning that anyone who searches  in the future for "long-to-wide [R]" will have more uncertainty on which post to choose.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe was sorted by ID, this would work. You add a column describing the groups of values that should go together in a column of the result, and then this works:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=rep(LETTERS,100),
                valueID=rep(1:100,each=26),
                values=rnorm(2600))
library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(df,ID~valueID)
```

So perhaps you could do

```
oo <- order(your.df$ID)
df <- cbind(your.df[oo,],valueID=paste0('value',rep(1:22721,each=34)))
```

and then do the what I did above. @akrun's data.table solution also works because N and ID together specify a unique cell, so mean doesn't contribute anything. But in both cases you need to sort first.